# Using AND OR in AmpScript IF THEN statement

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, if

I am can't figure out something I think is pretty simple.  I have an if/then statement and I want to evaluate three things:

```
%%[if @PromoCode == "XXXX" OR @Tier == "XXX" AND @Price == "100"  then]%%
```

What I am looking for is something like this:

```
(@PromoCode == "XXXX" OR @Tier == "XXX") AND @Price == "100"
```

How do I express that in an AMPscript If Then statement?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Should be something like this:

```
%%[ if (@PromoCode == "XXXX" OR @Tier == "XXX") AND @Price == "100" then ]%%

%%[ endif ]%%
```